# Sharepoint 2013 Web Part Custom Properties lost on redeploy

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, web-part

I've built some SharePoint 2013 web parts with custom properties.  They are deployed together via a single WSP solution.  The Web Parts work fine initially.  However, each time the solution is re-deployed, the customize properties are reset to their defaults, and the customized values are lost.  The date/time stamp of the files in the ./wp folder match that of the files in the FEATURES folder.

FYI, I notice the solution is deployed to the server (of which there is only one) http://etc rather than 'deployed globally'.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting the properties to their default values is a normal behavior after redeploying the WSP solution. Where the deployment steps are performed as the following

1. Run pre-deployment command.
2. Recycle IIS application pool.
3. Retract solution. (so the old properties values are reset)
4. Add solution. (add the solution with its default properties values)
5. Activate features.
6. Run post-deployment command.

Read more details about deployment process at [Deploying, Publishing, and Upgrading SharePoint Solution Packages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231559(v=vs.120).aspx) and See also [CREATE CUSTOM WEBPART PROPERTY FOR SHAREPOINT VISUAL WEBPART](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/23/create-custom-web-part-properties-for-visual-webpart-sharepoint2013/)